# Probability generating function of infinite sum of independent r.v.s

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

For all $i = 1, 2, 3...$, let $X_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_i).$ Suppose the $X_i$ are independent random variables. I wish to show that $X = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}  i X_i$ has probability generating function \begin{align} E(z^X) = \text{exp}(\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_i (z^i -1)). \end{align}
I have been able to *formally* obtain the above expression for the p.g.f, but am stuck in rigorously justifying one line at the start of the derivation, namely:
\begin{align}
E(z^{X}) = E(z^{\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j N_j}) \stackrel{(\star)}{=} \prod_{j=1}^{\infty} E(z^{jN_j}).
\end{align}
Here, I claim that $(\star)$ follows from the independence of the $N_j$'s. If there were only finitely many $X_j$'s, then the proof would inductively follow from:
\begin{align}
E(z^{X_1 + X_2}) = E(z^{X_1} z^{X_2}) = E(z^{X_1})E(z^{X_2}). \end{align}
But, how might I extend this to the infinite case?

Comment: It is an easy exercise to show that if $\sum_i \lambda_i<\infty$ and $X_i \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda_i)$, then $\sum_{i\geq 1}X_i \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\sum_i \lambda_i)$. Then you can conclude.

Comment: The chf is not well defined if $X = \infty$? If the sum for $X$ converges in distribution, then you get that the chf of $X$ is the limit of the chfs of the partial sums, which is the limit of the partial products of the chfs, which is the infinite product of the chfs.

Comment: @Andrew But each $X_i$ is multiplied by a coefficient "i"?

Comment: Expectation is linear and the Poisson distribution is completely characterized by its mean.